# Javascript - create array index and access

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am looking to create a simple array using a time stamp for the index so that I can access the values by timestamp without iterating through the array, however I am struggling!

I need to be able to set 2 values for each row.

For example:

```
var myarray = [];
var test1 = 'hello'
var test2 = 'world'

myarray[timestamp] = [test1, test2];
```

So for a given timestamp e.g. 12345678, how could I access the value of test2?

Appreciate any thoughts and advice.

Regards, Ben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use an array that way, you'll end up with an array containing a large amount of `undefined` values:

```
var myarr = [];
myarr[1000] = 'hello';
console.log(myarr.length); //=> 1001 
console.log(myarr[0]); //=> undefined
console.log(myarr[999]); //=> undefined
```

So, you may want to use an object for that and use some kind of sorting. For example

```
var myobj = {}, timestamp = new Date().getTime();
myobj[timestamp] =   ['hello','world'];
myobj[timestamp+1] = 'how are we today?';

function retrieveSorted(obj){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(), key, ret = [];
  while(key = keys.shift()){
    ret.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return ret;
}

var sorted = retrieveSorted(myobj); 
   //=> [["hello", "world"], "how are we today?"]
myobj[timestamp][1]; //=> world
```

Comment: Great job explaining the JavaScript array initialization issue, and proving a good alternative.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of JS engines in use today can handle sparse arrays pretty good, so there won't be much difference.

Comment: @KooiInc This is superb! I did indeed hit the initialisation issue, and hence why I was struggling. Thanks for the excellent advice.

Regards, Ben.

Comment: @Oleg: the maximum array length is 4294967295. If you use a timestamp index (which may be much larger than that maximum), the `length` of that array will actually be 0, and Array methods render more or less unusable (will not throw an error, but just won't return a value or not do what you expect them to do).

Answer (score 2):

```
myarray[timestamp][1]
```

1 is the 2nd index in inner array. Indexes start from 0.

Comment: In my experience, in yourArray[i][prop], the i is the counter that lets you access the object's property values. Cheers!